# In for each loop is it possible to get copy of object from collection

Tags: vb.net, ms-project

I am trying to create copy of collection and then delete original collection.
I am iterating over original collection using For Each loop and then add objects into new collection.
but as soon as I delete objects from original collection, I am not able to use newly created collection.
Count of objects in newly created collection is correct

rMSPCalendar.Exceptions is a collection provided by MSProject for each calendar
After this code if iterate over rMSPCalendarExceptions , I get error "Object required"

```
Dim rMSPCalendarExceptions As New Collection
Dim exception As Object
rMSPCalendar.Exceptions(1).
For Each exception In rMSPCalendar.Exceptions
   rMSPCalendarExceptions.Add exception
   exception.Delete
Next exception
```

Comment: post your coding....

Comment: When you say delete, do you mean you are disposing the objects?  If so, you are disposing the object that the reference in the new collection is pointing to.  Remember VB uses references.  Post your code.

Comment: it is for MS project, I have added code

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the generic `Collection` object and only populate it with the Name of the Exception (e.g. the default property), use a List of type `MSProject.Exception`:

```
Dim Exceptions As New List(Of MSProject.Exception)
For Each Ex As MSProject.Exception In rMSPCalendar.Exceptions
    Exceptions.Add(Ex)
    Ex.Delete()
Next
For Each Ex In Exceptions
    ' do something with the exception...
    Console.WriteLine(Ex.Name & vbTab & Ex.Start & vbTab & Ex.Finish)
Next
```

BTW: Since the word Exception refers to a native vb.net object, I suggest you change your variables to be more explicit--perhaps CalExceptions.